# HighCharts show selected point from chart on Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a scatter chart of points and I also have some of these points represented in a Pie Chart. I would like the appropriate Pie Chart slice to be selected if the user clicks on the corresponding point in the scatter chart.

I have the points x and y coordinates but I am unsure of how to call this on the pie chart.

Is there an ID as such for each slice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an id for each slice and if you have a corresponding id in the scatter chart, selecting the slice is easy.  This code needs error checking, but it should get you started.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            min: -0.5,
            max: 5.5
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Scatter plot with regression line'
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'scatter',
            name: 'Observations',
            data: [{id:'first', y:1}, 1.5, 2.8, 3.5, 3.9, {id:'last', y:4.2}],
            marker: {
                radius: 4
            },
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    var chart = $('#pie').highcharts();
                    var point = chart.get(event.point.id);
                    $(point).select();
                }
            }
        }]
    });

   $('#pie').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            min: -0.5,
            max: 5.5
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0
        },

        series: [{
            allowPointSelect: true,
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Observations',
            data: [{id:'first', y:1}, 1.5, 2.8, 3.5, 3.9, {id:'last', y:4.2}],
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ymf4x84m/